# why is there a cancel/replace message in FIX?

Tags: fix, order-handling, order

Couldn't we just cancel existing order and enter new order?

Is there any other reason apart from a communication overhead that now we need to send 2 messages vs just 1 message to cancel replace?

Answer (score 15):

1. Order Cancel-Replace might save you from losing priority in the book (for instance when cancelling some of the remaining shares - check the venue rules!).
2. The communication overhead is very significant - it halves the round trip time (otherwise you have to cancel; wait for confirmation; re-send -- if you don't wait you risk getting double fills).
3. At any given time you have your order active in the book (unless rejected).
4. Margin/risk checks might also be faster (vendor-specific of course)

Comment: Hi amsh, welcome to Quant.SE!

Comment: do you know a venue, that would keep your priority in the book when doing cancel-replace?

Comment: It depends on what parameters you change, as mentioned above - reducing the quantity will (usually) save your priority. As far as I know, most venues behave this way. For further reading (CME): http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Order+Functionalities#OrderFunctionalities-OrderModification

Comment: yeah, I was curious if there are venues, that allow to increase the quantity without loosing the priority.

Comment: I doubt it - very prone for abuse

Comment: Welcome to quant.exchange Amsh, +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It is aimed at maintaining order book priority based on most venues price/length/time order book priority logic.
The order cancel/replace request is used to change the parameters of an *existing* order and the intention is not to cancel an order outright or cancel remaining quantity after a trade.
Venue FIX API's are coded to see 2 distinct differences between cancel and cancel/replace.
However, certain amendments to the order will cause it to lose it's place in the order book.